# класс Void в AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-asynctask

Начал изучать AsyncTask, в одном из уроков увидел следующий код:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        tvInfo.setText("Begin");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        tvInfo.setText("End");
    }
}
```

Что за класс Void (с большой буквы), для чего он нужен и почему нельзя использовать обычный void?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Void - это "непримитивный аналог" `void`. Нужен для использования в параметризованных классах, т.к. параметром может быть только класс, а примитив быть параметром не может.

Вы можете смело использовать `Void` вместо `void`, также как, например `Integer` вместо `int`. Однако, в этом случае надо будет удовлетворять требования компилятора. Например для `void` методов `return` можно опустить, а вот для `Void` методов надо явно его прописать. Вот пример:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test();
        test1();
    }
    
    public static Void test() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        return null;
    }
    
    public static void test1() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

---

И вот ещё пара ссылок:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839042/what-is-the-difference-between-java-lang-void-and-void/12630665

https://www.baeldung.com/java-void-type

Comment: Премного благодарен!)